# Adapter for spinner does not return correct position of the string in android

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

I have an arraylist of type string which is assigned to spinner. When I use following code to set spinner's selection, it returns -1 as position although string is present in the list.

```
      int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(myString);
       ////here it returns -1
       //set the default according to value
       spinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

It returns correct position for some adapters but not for others. What can be possibly wrong?? String I passed in  "myString" variable is 100% correct and exists in the adapter list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, so I apologize if this is wrong. Don't have source code to look at right now.

but I think the getPosition() method does not perform a .equals() comparison, so you can't just pass in an equivalent string.  So don't do

```
myString = "asdf"; //myString is getting assigned a reference to a brand new string
spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(myString);
```

because mySpring is not pointing at the same object as the string in your array, even if `myString.equals(originalString)` may return true;

This should work:

```
//assign the reference to point at the exact same object that is in the ArrayList
myString = originalString; 
spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(myString);
```

Comment: well myString=originalString is what I am doing. I have saved the selected item of spinner in database and now i want to display it back in spinner.Its the same string,same spelling and all

Comment: Can you tell me what type of array or list you're using for your strings? Is it an ArrayList? Or is it a Cursor? What is your adapter extended from?

Comment: I am using Arraylist of type String

Comment: I think we'll need to see more code to figure this out. What adapter are you using? If you customized it by extending it, can you post the code from that?